# python apscheduler, an easier way to run jobs?

Tags: python, apscheduler

I have jobs scheduled thru `apscheduler`. I have 3 jobs so far, but soon will have many more. i'm looking for a way to scale my code.

Currently, each job is its own `.py` file, and in the file, I have turned the script into a function with `run()` as the function name. Here is my code.

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
import logging

import job1
import job2
import job3

logging.basicConfig()
sched = Scheduler()

@sched.cron_schedule(day_of_week='mon-sun', hour=7)

def runjobs():
    job1.run()
    job2.run()
    job3.run()    

sched.start()
```

This works, right now the code is just stupid, but it gets the job done. But when I have 50 jobs, the code will be stupid long. How do I scale it?

note: the actual names of the jobs are arbitrary and doesn't follow a pattern. The name of the file is `scheduler.py` and I run it using `execfile('scheduler.py')` in python shell.

Comment: Depends on the type of job. If the jobs are IO bound use the `threading` module, if they're computationally expensive use `multiprocessing`.

Comment: @John My jobs are not computationally expensive. Can you provide some examples? or point me to some examples of what you are talking about? would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import urllib
import threading
import datetime

pages = ['http://google.com', 'http://yahoo.com', 'http://msn.com']

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Getting the pages WITHOUT threads
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def job(url):
    response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    html = response.read()

def runjobs():
    for page in pages:
        job(page)

start = datetime.datetime.now()
runjobs()
end = datetime.datetime.now()

print "jobs run in {} microseconds WITHOUT threads" \
      .format((end - start).microseconds)

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Getting the pages WITH threads
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def job(url):
    response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    html = response.read()

def runjobs():
    threads = []
    for page in pages:
        t = threading.Thread(target=job, args=(page,))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    for t in threads:
        t.join()

start = datetime.datetime.now()
runjobs()
end = datetime.datetime.now()

print "jobs run in {} microsecond WITH threads" \
      .format((end - start).microseconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look @

http://furius.ca/pubcode/pub/conf/bin/python-recursive-import-test

This will help you import all python / .py files.

while importing you can create a list which keeps keeps a function call, for example.

[job1.run(),job2.run()]

Then iterate through them and call function :)

Thanks Arjun